# swift 速度を計測する方法

Tags: swift, xcode

速度を計測する方法をわかる方がいましたら、教えて下さい。
自転車の速度を計測する予定です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS のことは分からないのですが、こういった事を全部面倒見てくれる API は無いのではないでしょうか。 (追記: 瞬間的な速度を得られるAPIがあるようです。quesera2 さんのコメントを参照して下さい)
少し問題が大きすぎると思いますので、下記のように切り分けて一つずつ解決するのがよいと思います。

- 移動した距離の計測

  - スタート地点とゴール地点の緯度・経度の記録
  - 地球上の2点間の距離の計算
- 移動にかかった時間の計測

  - スタート時刻とゴール時刻の記録
  - 時刻の差による経過時間の計算
- 距離と時間による速度の計算

Comment: [Core Motionに速度を算出するAPI](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007126-CH3-SW24)自体はあります。ただ、それを利用すれば自転車の速度を出せるというレベルまで面倒を見てくれるものではないのですが…。

Comment: なるほど結構用意されている物ですね。目的によってはこの  CLLocationSpeed で事足りるかもしれませんね。

Comment: miyさん、quesera2さんありがとうございます。
miyさんのおっしゃるとおり、切り分けて行ってみます。